# Direct link to lightbox and automatically open

Tags: java, jquery, lightbox, lightbox2

I need to be able to directly link to images within a lightbox (currently using Lightbox2) from an external website. Basically I want to post a link to one of my images on say, Twitter, and have the link go to my website, open a lightbox, and display the image. I also need to be able to see the image link URL in the address bar while viewing the image in a lightbox. I found this: http://www.huddletogether.com/forum/comments.php?DiscussionID=1407 but it's for an old version of lightbox and for the life of me I couldn't get it work.

Here's a working example:
http://www.rudirakete.de/rudirakete/main#2008-10-5-1526107735

Answer (score 0):

Why not use jQuery [dialog()](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

```
var p = '<img src="http://www.geekologie.com/2007/12/07/future-car-1.jpg" />';
$('a').click(function() {
    $(p).dialog({
        minWidth: 500,
        buttons: {
            OK: function() {
                $(this).dialog("destroy");
            }
        }
    })
})
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/msKZt/3/

Comment: I need to be able to send the link to someone... So when the lightbox opens on the page, the address bar needs to change to something like http://example.com/#postid47839 or something like that. Then if say I just emails http://example.com/#postid47839 to a friend and they went to the URL, that specific image will open in a lightbox automatically.  I just need it to work exactly like this [http://www.huddletogether.com/forum/comments.php?DiscussionID=1407](http://www.huddletogether.com/forum/comments.php?DiscussionID=1407) but with the current version of Lightbox2.

Comment: Here's a working example of this, if you can tell me how this guy did it, [this is EXACTLY what I need:](http://www.rudirakete.de/rudirakete/main#2008-10-5-1526107735)

Comment: That URL contains the unique image ID in the #; he checks it with JS using window.location.hash, then fires lightbox.start() on the image link after page load.
With lightbox2 you can do this by $('#your-link).trigger('click');